# Dynamic credentials for firebase application initialization in firebase-messaging-sw.js file

Tags: javascript, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hi I have set up Javascript API for firebase push notifications on my website. I have created firebase-messaging-sw.js file in my website directory.

In the documentation it indicates that in the service worker the application has to be initialized with the burned credentials.

```
firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: "" })

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

Can the credentials be passed as a parameter to the service worker or how can I handle dynamic credentials?